# Is there a way to get all the properties of an object that could possibly be accessed by a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that is basically a list of functions, like:

```
const functions: FunctionList<IInputObj, IOutputObj> = {
    outputProperty1: function function1(IInputObjInstance) -> outputProperty1Type,
    outputProperty2: function function2(IInputObjInstance) -> outputProperty2Type,
};
```

Is there a way to produce an object or function that identifies which properties on IInputObjInstance were accessed by each outputProperty, like so:

```
function getInputPropertyNames(functions, outputPropertyName): string[] {
    switch(outputPropertyName) {
        case 'outputProperty1':
            return [inputProperty1, inputProperty3];
        case 'outputProperty2':
            return [inputProperty2];
    }
}
```

The functions may have `if` statements so that sometimes they access inputProperty1 and other times they access inputProperty3.

Using Proxy functions gets pretty close, but I'm not sure how to handle when the function could access different input properties depending on `if` statements.

https://2ality.com/2017/11/proxy-method-calls.html
https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_proxies.html#sec_design-proxy-api ("Tracing Property Accesses")

```
function tracePropAccess(obj: any, accesses: Array<string | number | symbol>) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
      get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            accesses.push(propKey);
            return Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
        },
      });
}

let accessesList: Array<string | number | symbol> = [];

class Point {
  x: Number;
  y: Number;
  z?: Number;
    constructor(x: Number, y: Number, z?: Number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        if (z) {
          this.z = z;
        }
    }
}

const pt = tracePropAccess(new Point(3, 2), accessesList);
console.log(pt.x());
console.log(pt.y());
console.log(pt.x());
console.log(pt.z());
console.log(accessesList);
```

This produces:

```
3
2
3
undefined
[ 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z' ]
```

I would like to get `accessesList` for every function in the FunctionList, and all the properties that could be accessed by it in any conditional statement path, not just the one that my example input happened to go down.

Comment: In the most generic form, this is equivalent to the halting problem, just so you know. So you might want to consider what cases you truly want to handle, and why.

Comment: When they can access different properties at different times, the problem is impossible. Maybe you can do it with static analysis instead, i.e. parsing the function with some library and enforcing that properties aren’t accessed by name dynamically (`this['x' + 'yz'] = foo`). What’s the list of properties going to be used for?

Comment: @Nit Oh dear. Maybe I will just have to suck it up and do this manually.

Comment: @Ry- The list is so that I can define error messages on the output properties, but link them back to the input properties they were derived from.